# Project "Gothonweb" in Learn Python the Hard Way ex50 works fine on Ubuntu, fails on win7

Tags: python

I did the project in ex50. It works fine on ubuntu. However I can't get it run normally on win7. What's wrong with it? (My code is exactly the same as what it is in the book!)

app.py

```
import web
urls = (
   '/', 'Index'
)
app = web.application(urls, globals())

render = web.template.render('templates/')

class Index(object):
    def GET(self):
        greeting = "Hello World"
    return render.Index(greeting = greeting)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Traceback on win7:[traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxCeK.png)
And my project here on github~ https://github.com/ustcgcy/gothonweb

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the trailing `/`on Windows. Instead of `render = web.template.render('templates/')` write `render = web.template.render('templates')`.

Comment: I've modified it but the traceback still occurs.

Comment: Your problem is likely in the HTML template. Try saving it without BOM in an editor with this capability such as Notepad++.

Comment: Actually I did use Notepad++ to edit the file and it is that format.